# WPF application fail to load C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, dll

I hava a WPF application which uses both C# and C++ dlls.
On most machines it works properly but I have a few machine which when trying to run the application on them it I get the exception: 
The module should contain an assembly manifest. (HRESULT:0x80131018)
I have no idea about this exception.
What can cause this behavior, and what can be the solution?

Comment: Do you have two assemblies with the same name? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ad17869-63cc-4529-bfaf-9099db500e0d/the-module-was-expected-to-contain-an-assembly-manifest

Comment: Are the dlls in the same place as the executable?

Comment: No. I have a few C# dlls and 2 C++ - each one has a different name. The C++ dlls fail to be loaded.

Comment: Yes. they are in the same folder.

Comment: Is it possible that the machines where the application fails are x64?

Comment: The machines are x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This HRESULT: 0x80131018 is return when a .NET application trying to load C++ assemblies as .NET dlls.
The problem ws that in the code I've tried to load C++ dlls via the command: 
`Assembly.LoadFile(path);`
The problem with the different OSs was depends on the different languages which return the error message in diverse sentences.